# Send Outlook meeting requests

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send meeting requests automatically using using PowerShell.

I manage to send a message using this command:

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer [mail-server-url] -From [sender-address] -To [recipient-address] -Subject [subject] -Body [body]
```

Also i saw that you can send meetings using this code:

`$olAppointmentItem = 1 
$o = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$a = $o.CreateItem($olAppointmentItem)
...
$a.Send()`

but i cant see where do i put the mail server url when sending a meeting...

Comment: You will need to edit your question and include your actual code that you are trying to get working.

Comment: Your first script block will only send a normal mail message, while the second script block will create an Outlook Calendar Item and send to the designated recipient.  You do not specify an SMTP server when using the second method.  It uses the locally installed Outlook instance to send the item.  Therefor, wherever you are attempting to send this from must have Outlook installed.  I recently was testing this same bit of code and I was unable to send as a mailbox other than myself.

Comment: I did a workaround for this issue and created and ics file which i attached to the message, but i still wished there was a more elegant way to do this.